# COM call returns int instead of decimal

Tags: c#, com, vb6

I am trying to call a legacy COM component from my C# code.
The signature of the method is shown below. Parameters 2 , 3 and 4 are reference parameters.

```
  GetCOMData(UserId As Long, arraySummary As Variant, startDate As Variant, endDate As Variant)
```

The problematic bit is parameter 2 (arraySummary). It seems the legacy code returns a array of variants in parameter 2 and all of them have different data types as shown below.

```
'                   Elements of arraySummary 
'                   0   -   int
'                   1   -   int 
'                   2   -   date 
'                   3   -   date
'                   4   -   decimal
'                   5   -   decimal
'                   6   -   decimal
'                   7   -   decimal
```

When the COM call is completed and the reference object is returned it seems that element 4 - 7 of arraySummary are getting truncated and are converted into int instead of the decimal .

My question is : Is there a way to tell Method.InvokeMember explicitly that I am expecting a decimal for array element 4 - 7 of parameter arraySummary ?

My C# code to call COM object is shown below :

```
 var parameters = new object[4];
        ParameterModifier p = new ParameterModifier(4);
        p[1] = true;
        p[2] = true;
        p[3] = true;
        ParameterModifier[] mods = { p };
        parameters[0] = UserID;
        Type t= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ComDLL.COMClass");
        object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        object recordSet = comObj .InvokeMember("GetCOMData", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObj , parameters, mods, null, null);
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you checked that is works correctly when called outside of .NET (for example, through VBA)?

Comment: not sure, but maybe you can send a user defined type as the 2nd argument ? in the type definition you can then specify the type of each element

Comment: @Heinzi  :  You are correct , when i test the  COM object in a way that it returns values which contain something after the decimal point  then it is detected as decimal by c#, if the value doesnt have anything after the decimal point , c# treats it as int( which is correct behaviour ) it seems i got myself confused with the behaviour of variants. .NET will convert the value to its nearest type depending on the data and since the data in my case did not have anything after the decimal , C# converted it into a int.

Comment: @Pat: Ah, that's interesting indeed! May I suggest that you write that down as an answer and "accept" your own answer? That way, your question won't show up in the "unanswered questions" list, and other people with the same problem can benefit from your findigs.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question, the COM function I was using returns a array of variants , C# inherently tries to convert the value of the variant to its nearest possible datatype.

Ex :
Below is sample of array elements and the corresponding type recognized by C#

Element#  Value   C# Recognized it as
 0          1             INT
 1          34            int
 2         24/1/2013      DateTime
 3         1/1/2013       dateTime
 4         1              INT ( since this no has no decimal part C# thinks its a int)
 5         2.63           DECIMAL ( recognized as decimal as this has a value after decimal point)

As you can see above for  element # 4 and 5 , C# converted them  to different data types based on the  value. This makes perfect sense (in hindsight) as C#  has no way to find out what is the actual data type and thus makes the most accurate guess.